# 「素早い」と「早い」ってどう違いますか？

Tags: translation, word-choice, words, usage, nuances

ビジュアルノベルを読んでいたら、次の文が出てきました。

> 少女は素早く辺りを見回し、護りの構えをとる。
>   The girl quickly takes a look around and assumes a defensive stance.

質問: **どうしてこの場合「素早い」が選ばれているのですか。「早い」でもいいのでしょうか。**

＊このポストは僕が初めて日本語だけで書いたものですので、誤りがあえば直してくださいませんか。

Comment: すみません、質問に関係ないですが、「ＶＮ」って何ですか。（ググったら「ベトナム」の略だって。。。）

Comment: @Chocolate VNって「ビジュアルノベル」という意味でしょうね？

Comment: おお・・それは、ゲームのように「プレイ」するものでしょうか、それとも読み物ですか？　「ＶＮを読んでいたら」のほうがいいでしょうか。

Comment: そんな事がわかりません。すみません

Comment: ごめん、私もわからない、あははｗｗ

Comment: テキストの多いので、私も「読む」を使うのがいいと初めて思っていました。ヒントでありがとうございました。

Comment: 日本語ではどうか分かりませんが、VNはゲームの一種であり、英語で "Read a visual novel" と "Play a visual novel" の言い方は両方使われています。

Comment: @Otsukisama You probably misused VNって「ビジュアルノベル」という意味でしょうね？because it says "You of course said VN in the sense of visual novel, didn't you?".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

英語の返事ですみません。

「早い」 is a more general term used to mean 'fast'. It can also mean 'early', as in 'early in the morning' (朝早い仕事とか）.

「素早い」specifically refers to the time taken to perform an action - an English equivalent adverb would be 'quickly', but also would mean 'deftly' or 'nimbly', and I would say in my experience implies a degree of efficiency - in your example, the girl's quick judgement of the situation.

They have slightly different applications, and although I would say they are interchangeable in this instance without sounding *too* off, 素早い is a bit more precise.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

In such cases it helps to consult a monolingual (kokugo) dictionary. For example, here's the [definition from Daijirin](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E7%B4%A0%E6%97%A9%E3%81%84-542997):

> ①  動作や行動が早い。敏捷{びんしよう}だ。手早い。 「動作が－・い」 「ボールを－・く投げ返す」
>
> ②  理解や判断が早い。 「彼の真意を－・く見抜く」 「経済の動きを－・く読み取る」

---

> 1. Fast of movement or action. Nimble. Agile.
>
> 「動作が素早い」 [one's] movement(s) are fast
>
> 「ボールを素早く投げ返す」quickly return the ball
>
> 2. Quick to comprehend or decide.
>
> 「彼の真意を素早く見抜く」 Quickly see through his real intentions
>
> 「経済の動きを素早く読み取る」Quickly grasp market movements